# Is the first item returned by get_posts() always the latest post?

Tags: php, get-posts

I want to retrieve the modification date of the latest post. To do this, first I get the latest post:

```
$latest_post = get_posts()[0];
```

Can I be certain that the returned object is always the latest post or are there circumstances where the order of objects returned by `get_posts()` is different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and Maybe

Yes: According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/ the default is ordered by date in a descending order.

Maybe: But plugins may change the query through ie hook(s) **pre_get_posts**.

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/featured_content/pre_get_posts/